# Different Local Values and Master Values for PHP Session settings

Tags: php, memcached

I have configured `PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2015 21:17:27)` on Centos7.0 to use memcached for session handling.

```
[Session]
; Handler used to store/retrieve data.
; http://php.net/session.save-handler
session.save_handler = memcached

session.save_path = "tcp://127.0.0.1:11211"
```

According to `phpinfo()`, the Local Values for `session.save_handler` & `session.save_path` are different to the Master values.

The Master Values are as indicated in the php.ini file.

[image]

I can’t see these Local Values being set in .htaccess, under  /etc/httpd or in the PHP code base.

Is there somewhere else that they are likely to come from or are these fallback values that might indicate a problem with my `memcached` configuration. If so, how does one fix this?

I can verify that `memcached` is working by using an example like [this one from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-memcache-on-ubuntu-14-04) and seeing the data in a telnet session.

```
<?php

$mem = new Memcached();
$mem->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);

$result = $mem->get("blah");

if ($result) {
    echo $result;
} else {
    echo "No matching key found.  I'll add that now!";
    $mem->set("blah", "I am data!  I am held in memcached!") or die("Couldn't save anything to memcached...");
}
?>
```

I have also tried adding these lines to a .htaccess file.

```
php_flag session.save_handler "memcached"
php_flag session.save_path "127.0.0.1:11211"
```

But the values appeared zeroed out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Centos7.0 PHP package comes with an additional Apache Confuration file that is confusingly called `php.ini`. This contains statements that override the `session.save_handler` and `session.save_path` variables.

```
$ egrep -rI php_  /etc/httpd/
/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf:php_value session.save_handler "files"
/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf:php_value session.save_path    "/var/lib/php/session"
```

Comment: This is true even for PHP7.2